# How to quickly create an empty wide table in DolphinDB?

Tags: datatable, dolphindb

Supposing the result of the `createTimeSeriesEngine` function contains more than 100 columns, is there an easy way to set an empty wide table as the outputTable?

Answer (score 0):

If the column names share a prefix or suffix (e.g. factor001-factor100) and have the same data type (e.g. DOUBLE), you can use `table(1:0, "factor" + lpad(string(1..100), 3, "0"), take(DOUBLE, 100))` to quickly create an empty table with 100 columns.